# QuickBooks REST API v3.0 ( PHP SDK ) Integration

Tags: quickbooks-online

I have installed PHP SDK for quickbook.

I have configured,

```
 AccessTokenSecret
 ConsumerKey
 ConsumerSecret
 RealmID
```

When i was executin the file create_customer.php

(v3-php-sdk-1.0.0/_Samples/create_customer.php).

### I'm having this error,

### Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in D:\wamp\www\QB\Core\RestCalls\SyncRestHandler.php on line 194

I couldnot find the class OAuth . I have entire SDK folder, but i couldn't find. 
Can any one help me regarding this issue.

I am very much in need of it.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 3):

You're using unreleased code from Intuit that doesn't actually work correct - the code you're using is broken.

Instead of using that, use the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) that's available on GitHub. It's open-source and well supported, and works fine with OAuth and v3.

You can follow the [QuickBooks PHP IPP v3 Quick-Start Guide](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start) to get started. You'll go through a similar process to what you went through above, where you'll find in your own OAuth token/secret and app token in the configuration, and then you'll be able to connect to QuickBooks.

From there, you'll find several example scripts - your code for add customers ends up looking something like this (example from GitHub repo here: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/example_customer_add.php):

```
<?php

// Set up the IPP instance
$IPP = new QuickBooks_IPP($dsn);

// Get our OAuth credentials from the database
$creds = $IntuitAnywhere->load($the_username, $the_tenant);

// Tell the framework to load some data from the OAuth store
$IPP->authMode(
    QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTH, 
    $the_username, 
    $creds);

// Print the credentials we're using
//print_r($creds);

// This is our current realm
$realm = $creds['qb_realm'];

// Load the OAuth information from the database
if ($Context = $IPP->context())
{
    // Set the IPP version to v3 
    $IPP->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);

    $CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

    $Customer = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer();
    $Customer->setTitle('Mr');
    $Customer->setGivenName('Keith');
    $Customer->setMiddleName('R');
    $Customer->setFamilyName('Palmer');
    $Customer->setDisplayName('Keith R Palmer Jr ' . mt_rand(0, 1000));

    if ($resp = $CustomerService->add($Context, $realm, $Customer))
    {
        print('Our new customer ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
    }
    else
    {
        print($CustomerService->lastError($Context));
    }

    /*
    print('<br><br><br><br>');
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    print('Request [' . $IPP->lastRequest() . ']');
    print("\n\n\n\n");
    print('Response [' . $IPP->lastResponse() . ']');
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    */
}
else
{
    die('Unable to load a context...?');
}


?>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Palmer for your support.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little late but the error is caused by not having PECL oauth setup correctly.

There can be a couple reason why it is not setup correctly
1) It is not installed
Test: in terminal type: pecl list
If you see oauth in the response then you have it installed
If you don't have it installed you can follow this guide to get it installed: http://sergiopvilar.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/how-to-install-php-oauth-extension/

2) You did not update your php.ini file to use oauth
Often times you will have more than one php.ini file. Here is a good resource for the different locations. https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file

You need to add "extension=oauth.so" to the end of your php.ini file(s) then restart apache to get the changes to take effect.

Once you fix that the library should work.